Dconf reset error in Ubuntu 24.04 lts
I AM trying to restore Ubuntu 24.04 LTS to default settings. Saw a YouTube tutorial and tried
Sudo dconf reset -f /

However i received the mensage (original spanish): "error: failed to execute child process 'dbus-launch' (file or directory does Not exist)."
